# Describe the prompt I see when I first logged into the Linux computer

Tags: command-line, prompt

Can you please describe and explain each part of the command prompt

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

This is what I saw when I first logged in to my Linux computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set this with the `PS1` environment variable.

- `pi` is the username.
- `raspberrypi` is the name of the server.
- `~` is the current directory (and means 'home dir')
- `$` is the prompt - `$` denotes a non privileged user. (`#` denotes root).

`PS1` is probably set to:

```
PS1='\u@\h \w \$'
```

Comment: A nice how-to: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/index.html

Comment: Please note that `$` and `#` are by convention only, not enforced based on the user id in bash in any way. Nor is the username, hostname etc guaranteed to be used in the PS1, they could be fixed strings, although of course most likely they are. The prompt on the  bananapi  I have access to looks exactly the same, but its PS1 is more complex (it is for zsh, with colors in the prompt).

Comment: The `\$` option in the `PS1` does the `$` to `#` transition automatically. Most of the above _could_ be static, but I've assumed not when it's trivial to do it dynamically.